# cann anyone solve this questino?

Tags: malware

Routers on the internet never forward packets coming from private IP addresses Explain. Can you see any advantage in this?

Comment: this sounds a lot like homework. We don't disallow homework questions, but we prefer you to show *your* understanding of the question/answer and then we can help you refine it from there.

Comment: Posting the question straight off your assignment sheet won't impress anyone.

Answer (score 6):

Read [RFC 1918](http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc1918.txt) - it explains it all.

Answer (score 2):

Routers on the internet *should* never forward packets coming from private RFC1918 addresses. Sometimes they do, usually through misconfiguration or cablemodem provider suboptimality.

And to answer the second question, yes, I can see advantage in this.